# Why would a function use the "address of" operator on an argument passed to it as a pointer?

Tags: c

I am new to the C programming language and I am trying to understand the intent of a function which takes a pointer argument but uses the address of operator on it as though it was a variable name in the function's body? The parameters being passed are of type struct.  In other words, why did the author choose to use &lib -> fatfs; instead of lib->fatfs?   Is the "address of" operator used to ensure that a null pointer is not being passed?

```
void SDCardLib_init(SDCardLib * lib, SDCardLib_Interface * interface)
{
    lib->interface = interface;

    f_mount(0, &lib->fatfs);

    disk_initCallBack(interface);
}
```

Comment: Maybe because `lib->fatfs` is a non-pointer object, and the `f_mount` function expects to be passed a pointer?

Comment: It could also possibly be a way to *emulate pass by reference in C*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address-of operator is not being applied to the pointer `lib` but to the `fatfs` member of the pointed to object.  The `->` operator has higher precedence then the unary `&` operator.

That means that `&lib->fatfs` is the same as `&(lib->fatfs)`.  This should make it more clear what `&` is taking the address of.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, I completely missed the precedence possibility. Could you say a little more about why the author would want the &(lib->fatfs) address? Does this allow the author to bind the address to their own internal pointer as a way to map a logical name to a physical name?

Comment: @user3062695 I can't really say as there is very little context to this code.

Answer (score 4):

`&lib->fatfs` is the same as `&(lib->fatfs)` or `&((*lib).fatfs)`. The `&` doesn't take the address of the pointer named `lib`.

`&lib->fatfs` is essentially whatever `lib` points at plus whatever offset the `fatfs` member is at.

The following piece of code asserts that:

```
//imagine a fake SDCardLib
typedef long sometype;
typedef struct {
    int something0;
    sometype fatfs;
    int something1;
} SDCardLib;

#undef NDEBUG //make sure asserts are kept
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h> //offsetof
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc
int main()
{
    SDCardLib *lib = malloc(sizeof *lib);
    if(!lib) return 1;

    assert( &lib->fatfs  ==
                (sometype*) ((char*)lib + offsetof(SDCardLib,fatfs)) );

    assert( &lib->fatfs == &(lib->fatfs) );
    assert( &lib->fatfs == &((*lib).fatfs) );
}
```

Comment: thank you. I completely missed the precedence order. Could you say a little more about the author's intent in this statement?